# How do I pass a semicolon as a literal in a batch file subroutine

Tags: batch-file

Given the following Windows batch (.cmd) file,

```
@echo off
call :Test arg1; arg2
exit /B

:Test
echo %1
echo %2
exit /B
```

This displays:

```
arg1
arg2
```

How do I pass the semicolon as a literal so it displays:

```
 arg1;
 arg2
```

Thanks very much

UPDATE:

Ok, to make things clearer I'm really trying to do something like this:

```
@echo off
call :Execute "c:\Program Files (x86)\Whatever\Test.exe" arg1 arg2
exit /B

:Execute
echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
exit /B
```

Only commands I want echoed will therefore be passed to "Execute" (with a variable number of args). However, these args may contain characters like a semicolon so they need to be passed literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the output of this batch:

```
@echo off
call :Execute "c:\Program Files (x86)\Whatever\Test.exe" arg1; arg2
exit /B

:Execute
echo * %*
echo - %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
%*
exit /B
```

Output

```
* "c:\Program Files (x86)\Whatever\Test.exe" arg1; arg2
- "c:\Program Files (x86)\Whatever\Test.exe" arg1 arg2
```

Comment: That looks perfect. Hopefully no issues will surface but will be investigating (seems to be working without issue so far). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon `;` constitutes a token separator just like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the comma `,`, the equal-to sign `=` and the non-break space (code `0xFF`). If you want them to be included in a command line argument literally, you need to enclose the argument within quotation marks `""`:

```cmd
@echo off
call :SUB semicolon;lost "some  spaces " "semicolon;kept",  no,comma  "a,comma"
exit /B

:SUB
echo ORIGINAL ARGUMENTS:
echo(%*
echo PARSED ARGUMENTS (EACH ENCLOSED IN ""):
:LOOP
if "%~1"=="" goto :EOF
echo("%~1"
shift /1
goto :LOOP
```

The output will be:

> ```cmd
> ORIGINAL ARGUMENTS:
> semicolon;lost "some  spaces " "semicolon;kept",  no,comma  "a,comma"
> PARSED ARGUMENTS (EACH ENCLOSED IN ""):
> "semicolon"
> "lost"
> "some  spaces "
> "semicolon;kept"
> "no"
> "comma"
> "a,comma"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the semicolon in quotes and remove the quotes later on:

```
@echo off
call :Test "arg1;" arg2
exit /B

:Test
echo %~1
echo %2
exit /B
```

---

An alternative which prints the arguments unchanged:

```
@echo off
call :Test arg1; arg2
exit /B

:Test
FOR /F %%I IN ("%*") DO echo %%I
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it to work the way I posted it. "Test" will actually be called with arbitrary variables so I don't know which, if any, will contain the semicolon. Do you know if it's doable as originally posted? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what I'm really exploring is a way to echo specific commands while leaving all others silent. I'm looking at setting @echo off at the start of my batch file and for specific commands only would call "Test" (I'll actually rename this to "Execute" or whatever). That subroutine would then echo all its args and then immediately execute them (so %1 inside of "Test" would be the name of the ".exe", and %2, %3, %4, etc. would be its args). Maybe there's a better way to do this.